# Difference between pagecontrol and pageviewcontroller ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

What is the difference between `UIpageControl` and `UIpageViewController`? What are their use case where these control should used ?

I have created a uipageviewcontroller demo in which  i created a pageviewcontroller and for its content i have taken a content view where i am using a image view to change the image on each left or right gesture by user (But haven't used the gesture function for them). When i try to left/right scroll them image just load and disappear and the view which is root view appear.

How can i remove this bug?

Below is the code for the datasource function i have used This is the datasource code that i am using to change the image of the content view:

```
#pragma mark datasource pagecontroller 

-(UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController 
     viewControllerBeforeViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    _currentIndex--;

    if(_currentIndex == 0)
    {
        return nil;
    } else {
        return [self viewControllerAtIndex:_currentIndex];
    }

}

- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController
       viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{    
    _currentIndex++;

    if(_currentIndex == 4)
    {
        return nil;
    } else {
        return [self viewControllerAtIndex:_currentIndex];
    }
}

- (ContentViewController *)viewControllerAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{    
    NSLog(@"~~~~~%lu   %@" ,(unsigned long)index , [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[pageContent objectAtIndex:_currentIndex]]);

    childViewController.imgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[pageContent objectAtIndex:_currentIndex]]];

    //childViewController.imgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"page3.png"];

    return childViewController;
}
```

Comment: Where are you instantiating `childViewController`? You have put `childViewController.imgView.image = ...` but you haven't actually created `childViewController`. Actually, let me edit my answer.

Comment: i initialized the content view object in view did load function but if i try to use your code it just behave same i mean if i initialize it in the viewcontrolleratindex it just behave same.

Comment: My code? You mean my edit just now?

Comment: Yes i tried that in my code but still it is not working right.

Comment: What exactly IS it doing? You said it isn't working right but you haven't said what it is doing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`UIPageViewController` is a container controller. It manages the display of several view controllers with scrolling between them.

`UIPageControl` is the series of little dots that displays which page you are on.

They are completely unrelated to each other. But they can be used together.

As for your "bug" we'll have to see the code in your page view controller datasource. You don't need to use your own gesture recognisers. The page view controller manages the scrolling itself.

**EDIT**

Your datasource method should look something like this...

```
- (ContentViewController *)viewControllerAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index {
    MyImageViewController *controller = [MyImageViewController new];

    controller.imgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[pageContent objectAtIndex:_currentIndex]]];

    return controller;
}
```

At the moment there seems to be only one controller `childViewController`. This means that you are trying to create the same one over and over. You need to create new controllers and populate them.

Comment: You can see my whole code at here : https://www.dropbox.com/s/prxu0jjwdswhj1u/PageViewController%202.zip?dl=0 Please let me know what is the issue in this code ?

Comment: OK, there is a lot to fix here. Your code is getting you confused. Let me update it to modern syntax and stuff and send it back.

Comment: @Ballu You've basically ignored every update to Objective-C for the past 3 years. Synthesise isn't needed, iVars for no apparent reason, you didn't actually update the method to use my code, you were still returning `childViewController`. You should delete `childViewController` entirely, not needed. This is stuff that any basic tutorial will show you.

Comment: @Ballu That is a poor excuse. I started to code with iOS3. The whole point of being a developer is to learn more and more as you go. If things are updated then you follow the updates and learn them.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65950/discussion-between-ballu-and-fogmeister).

Answer (score 4):

[UIPageViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPageViewControllerClassReferenceClassRef/index.html) is a class from the UIKit framework that can
be used in order to display a collection of UIViewControllers.

Unlike other container classes like `UINavigationController` or
`UITabBarController`, this class arranges all views either horizontally
or vertically in a line.

In order to switch between two screens, users
can use the swipe gesture where as the [UIPageControl](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPageControl_Class/index.html) are dots
that displays on which page you are on (visible to the user).